# Swap a file in Perfoce

Tags: binary, replace, perforce, swap

In perforce, I can mark for add/mark for delete files. However how can i swap files: replacing an old file with a new file with the same name? I have a couple binary files controlled by Perforce and I would like to replace. It's not a normal change/update case...

Newbie in Perforce. Many thanks!

Comment: Related, how would one go about swapping two existing files? Is there any way to perform a bidirectional "p4 move"? I want to preserve both revision histories if possible. Is there any approach better than opening both files for edit and swapping their contents?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isn't this just the normal change/update case?  It's just that the change to that particular file is rather extensive:

1. check out the file in Perforce
2. copy the new data over that file
3. commit the changed file to Perforce

Comment: I would second that this sounds like the normal change/update case.  But, if for some reason you wanted to destroy the revision history of this file forever, and then start fresh with a new file, a Perforce admin can do what is called "obliterate" the file.  But, this case should be rare.  Otherwise, more clarification about your situation is necessary here.

Comment: Obliterate isn't the answer.  Just check-in the new versions of the binary files.